# Page template not registering on theme

Tags: templates, user-registration

I have the following code for a page. When I select the template Home Page from the drop down menu in the page edit, it doesn't work on my web host, but locally it works fine, so I don't think it is my code. I don't know why its not working though.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name:Home Page
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
test
<div class="row">
    <div id="welcome" class="seven columns centered">
    <?php 
        $page_id = 2; 
        $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
        echo $content;

    ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a difference in query methods. This is a simpler way to query a page's content and can be used multiple times in a template without each query conflicting with each other.

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('page_id=2'); ?>

<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: This seemed to work. It also fixed it self when I renamed the home.php file to something else, not sure why that would be.